# Creating one table from select query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
  Select    
    Books.IdBooks,
    Books.Title,
    Books.Author,
    COUNT(Books.IdBooks) as NumberOfOrderedBooks

    From Books
    right join Orders
      on (Books.IdBooks = Orders.IdBooks)
    group by
        Books.IdSeminar,
        Books.Naziv
```

This select query works fine,  but I would like to create table from this query in SQL 2012, and I dont know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you can use a [INTO CLAUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) like so,

```
Select    
  Books.IdBooks,
  Books.Title,
  Books.Author,
  COUNT(Books.IdBooks) as NumberOfOrderedBooks
Into NEW_TABLE
From Books
right join Orders
  on (Books.IdBooks = Orders.IdBooks)
group by
    Books.IdSeminar,
    Books.Naziv
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch by like 4 seconds